# Pandas DataFrame column value remapping

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [8,16,23,8,23], 'count': [5,8,7,1,2]}, columns=['id', 'count'])

   id  count
0   8      5
1  16      8
2  23      7
3   8      1
4  23      2
```

...is there some Pandas magic that allows me to remap the ids so that the ids become sequential? Looking for a result like:

```
   id  count
0   0      5
1   1      8
2   2      7
3   0      1
4   2      2
```

where the original ids `[8,16,23]` were remapped to `[0,1,2]`

*Note:* the remapping doesn't have to maintain original order of ids. For example, the following remapping would also be fine: `[8,16,23] -> [2,0,1]`, but the id space after remapping should be contiguous.

I'm currently using a `for` loop and a `dict` to keep track of the remapping, but it feels like Pandas might have a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html#pandas-factorize):

```
>>> df
   id  count
0   8      5
1  16      8
2  23      7
3   8      1
4  23      2
>>> df['id'] = pd.factorize(df['id'])[0]
>>> df
   id  count
0   0      5
1   1      8
2   2      7
3   0      1
4   2      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a groupby's labels:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   id  count
0   8      5
1  16      8
2  23      7
3   8      1
4  23      2

In [12]: g = df.groupby("id")

In [13]: g.grouper.labels
Out[13]: [array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2])]

In [14]: df["id"] = g.grouper.labels[0]

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   id  count
0   0      5
1   1      8
2   2      7
3   0      1
4   2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you.

```
x,y = pd.factorize(df['id'])
remap = dict(set(zip(list(x),list(y))))
```